# When creating a Google Sheet with C#, how do I select a folder location?

Tags: api, google-sheets

I have the following code that creates a Google Sheet in my root drive folder:

```
    static void CreateSheet()
    {

        // Create a new sheet with a single tab
        string sheetName = "Test Create Sheet";
        var NewSheet = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet();
        NewSheet.Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
        NewSheet.Properties.Title = sheetName;
        
        var newSheet = service.Spreadsheets.Create(NewSheet).Execute();

        SpreadsheetId = newSheet.SpreadsheetId;
        Sheet = "Sheet1";

    }
```

I cannot seem to find syntax to update the location by folderid.

Is this even an option?

Comment: Have you already stumbled upon this **official Google documentation for Sheet API** that says ["There’s no option to create a spreadsheet directly within a specified Drive folder using the Sheets API"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#work_with_google_drive_folders)?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 I missed this, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Posted this as an answer to your post just in case other new members have the same concern. You may want to up-vote/ accept it by doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be answered. That way, they'll be easily recommended  to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this even an option? [Answer:] **No**

According to the [*official Google documentation*](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#work_with_google_drive_folders) for creating a spreadsheet using the ***Sheets API***:

*"There’s no option to create a spreadsheet directly within a specified Drive folder using the Sheets API. By default, the created spreadsheet is saved to the user’s root folder on Drive."*

However, there are **alternative options** to saving a file to a Drive folder provided in the official documentation that will point you in the right direction.